# error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x6f697483). The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation

Tags: swift, exception, core-data, alamofire

After getting API success response, I am saving, updating and fetching the data from core data DB.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

protocol WKQuizInformationVMDelegate {
  func success(details: QuizDetails?, isSuccess: Bool, quizID: String)
  func detailsFailure(error: String, quizID: String)
}

class WKQuizInformation: NSObject {

 var quizDetails: QuizDetails?
 var delegate: WKQuizInformationVMDelegate?

 //Retrieve Particular Quiz Information from server
 func retrieveParticularQuizInfo(quizID : String, quizVersion : String, summary: String) {

     WKNetworkManager.sharedInstance.getParticularQuizDetail(clientUserID: WKQuizConstant.kClientUserIdValue, quizID: quizID, quizVersion: quizVersion, summary: summary, onSuccess: { (json) in

        self.saveUpdateQuizInfoDB(json: json)
        self.perform(#selector(self.fetchQuiz(quizID:)), with: quizID, afterDelay: 0.2) 

    }) { (error) in

        print(quizID)
        print(error)
        self.delegate?.detailsFailure(error: error, quizID: quizID)
    }
}

//MARK:- Save and Update Quiz Information in Data base
fileprivate func saveUpdateQuizInfoDB(json: JSON) {

    let quizInfo = FetchDataBaseService.sharedInstance.fetchQuizInformation(quizID: json[WKQuizConstant.Id].rawString() ?? "")

    var quizInfoDB: DBQuizInformation!

    if quizInfo.count > 0 {
        quizInfoDB = quizInfo[0]
    }

    else {
        quizInfoDB = DBQuizInformation.init(context : FetchDataBaseService.sharedInstance.mngdCntxt)
    }

    quizInfoDB.id = json[WKQuizConstant.Id].rawString() ?? ""
    quizInfoDB.quizVersion = json[WKQuizConstant.kQuizVersion].rawString() ?? ""
    quizInfoDB.newQuestions = json[WKQuizConstant.kNewQuestions].rawString() ?? ""
    quizInfoDB.navigationType = json[WKQuizConstant.kNavigationType].rawString() ?? ""
    quizInfoDB.testMode = json[WKQuizConstant.kTestMode].rawString() ?? ""
    quizInfoDB.questionTime = json[WKQuizConstant.kQuestionTime].rawString() ?? ""
    quizInfoDB.metadataAssoc = json[WKQuizConstant.kMetadataAssoc].rawString() ?? ""
    quizInfoDB.randomizeQuestion = json[WKQuizConstant.kRandomizeQuestion].rawString() ?? ""
    quizInfoDB.metadataTitle = json[WKQuizConstant.kMetadataTitle].rawString() ?? ""
    quizInfoDB.gotWrong = json[WKQuizConstant.kGotWrong].rawString() ?? ""
    quizInfoDB.quizTime = json[WKQuizConstant.kQuizTime].rawString() ?? ""
    quizInfoDB.title = json[WKQuizConstant.kTitle].rawString() ?? ""
    quizInfoDB.numberOfQuestions = json[WKQuizConstant.kNumberOfQuestions].rawString() ?? ""
    quizInfoDB.quizType = json[WKQuizConstant.kQuizType].rawString() ?? ""
    quizInfoDB.randomizeAnswer = json[WKQuizConstant.kRandomizeQuestion].rawString() ?? ""
    quizInfoDB.numberOfAvailableMetadataQuestions = json[WKQuizConstant.kNumberOfAvailableMetadataQuestions].rawString() ?? ""
    quizInfoDB.totalTestQuestions = json[WKQuizConstant.kTestProgress][WKQuizConstant.kTotalTestQuestions].rawString() ?? ""
    quizInfoDB.totalCorrectAnswers = json[WKQuizConstant.kTestProgress][WKQuizConstant.kTotalCorrectAnswers].rawString() ?? ""
    quizInfoDB.totalWrongAnswers = json[WKQuizConstant.kTestProgress][WKQuizConstant.kTotalWrongAnswers].rawString() ?? ""
    quizInfoDB.totalUnAttempted = json[WKQuizConstant.kTestProgress]["totalUnattempted"].rawString() ?? ""
    quizInfoDB.numberOfMetadataQuestions = Int64(json[WKQuizConstant.kNumberOfMetadataQuestions].rawValue as? Int ?? 0)

    FetchDataBaseService.sharedInstance.saveContext()
}

//Fetch Quiz Information from DB and Save it to models
@objc func fetchQuiz (quizID: String) {

    let fetchQuizInfo = FetchDataBaseService.sharedInstance.fetchQuizInformation(quizID: quizID)

    if fetchQuizInfo.count > 0 {

        let value = fetchQuizInfo[0]

        quizDetails = QuizDetails(quizVersion: value.quizVersion!,
                                       newQuestions: value.newQuestions!,
                                       navigationType: value.navigationType!,
                                       testMode: value.testMode!,
                                       questionTime: value.questionTime!,
                                       metadataAssoc: value.metadataAssoc!,
                                       randomizeQuestion: value.randomizeQuestion!,
                                       id: value.id!,
                                       metadataTitle: value.metadataTitle!,
                                       gotWrong: value.gotWrong!,
                                       quizTime: value.quizTime!,
                                       title: value.title!,
                                       numberOfQuestions: value.numberOfQuestions!,
                                       quizType: value.quizType!,
                                       randomizeAnswer: value.randomizeAnswer!,
                                       numberOfAvailableMetadataQuestions: value.numberOfAvailableMetadataQuestions!,
                                       totalTestQuestions: value.totalTestQuestions!,
                                       totalCorrectAnswers: value.totalCorrectAnswers!,
                                       totalWrongAnswers: value.totalWrongAnswers!,
                                       totalUnAttempted: value.totalUnAttempted!,
                                       numberOfMetadataQuestions: Int(value.numberOfMetadataQuestions))


        self.delegate?.success(details: quizDetails, isSuccess: true, quizID: quizID)
    }

    else {
        self.delegate?.success(details: nil, isSuccess: false, quizID: quizID)
    }
  }
}
```

WKQuizInformationVMDelegate is my protocol. QuizDetails is my model structure.

I have created a structure(model), while fetching the data from core data I am creating model and passing to it my controller class via delegate.

I don't know sometimes it is working fine but sometimes sudden crash occurs.

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x50000010)

I tried different ways also but getting crash unexpectedly.

Is there anything related to database I have to change ?
Or any other concept?

```
'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x9180952e)
frame #0: 0x00dc7b4c libswiftCore.dylib`swift_unknownRelease + 8
frame #1: 0x000caa00 WKQuiz`WKQuizInformation.quizDetails.setter(value=WKQuiz.QuizDetails @ 0x0064e6c8, self=0x1805d290) at WKQuizInfoVM.swift:0
* frame #2: 0x000d59a8 WKQuiz`WKQuizInformation.fetchQuiz(quizID="307", self=0x1805d290) at WKQuizInfoVM.swift:90
frame #3: 0x000d8fe0 WKQuiz`@objc WKQuizInformation.fetchQuiz(quizID:) at WKQuizInfoVM.swift:0
frame #4: 0x1d04602e Foundation`__NSFireDelayedPerform + 458
frame #5: 0x1c6d0636 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 14
frame #6: 0x1c6d0338 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoTimer + 832
frame #7: 0x1c6cfd36 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoTimers + 188
frame #8: 0x1c6cddd4 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 780
frame #9: 0x1c6211ae CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
frame #10: 0x1c620fd0 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
frame #11: 0x1ddcbb40 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 80
frame #12: 0x219a91d2 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 150
frame #13: 0x001d6114 WKQuiz`main at AppDelegate.swift:15
frame #14: 0x1be0e4ea libdyld.dylib`start + 2
```

Comment: Is there any error message in console/debugguer when it crashes?

Comment: No but threads it showing and message is coming "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x50000010)" to the line of structure.

Comment: What does the stack trace look like for the thread that crashes?

Comment: Please check I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot wrong with your code.

1. delegates must be set as weak.
2. `fetchQuiz` appears to read using the Main Managed Object Context.  You can only run this method from the main thread. Add a `DispatchQueue.main.async {` to ensure this
3. Every `!` is you asking the code to crash and should be removed
4. methods should return what you are asking for, or should be called with a completion block to return what you are asking for.  Your code is returning values using a delegate.  Which is wrong.
5. ManagedObjects (like `QuizDetails`) are not thread safe - neither for reading or for writing.  They must be accessed from the thread associated with their context.  It looks like you have only one context, so I assume that a main-thread context.
6. ManagedObjects that are removed from the store do not automatically get set to nil. If you are holding a pointer to them after they are deleted you will crash.  It is better to use a NSFetchedResultsController - even for just one object.
7. The `perform afterDelay` has no value.  I suspect it was added to prevent a race condition, or to otherwise paper over bugs.
8. in `fetchQuiz` there does not appear to be a reason that you are creating a `QuizDetails` when you already have the one you just fetched stored in the variable `value`

All of these are real issues that should be fixed.  the most likely immediate cause of your crash is #2 - (accessing core data from the wrong thread).  replace

```
    self.saveUpdateQuizInfoDB(json: json)
    self.perform(#selector(self.fetchQuiz(quizID:)), with: quizID, afterDelay: 0.2)
```

with

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.saveUpdateQuizInfoDB(json: json)
        self.fetchQuiz(quizID:quizID)
    }
```

Comment: I did the same,
but still getting crash.

Comment: This was really helpful mate :) +1